# C - Split Slows Down My Computer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, split, double-pointer

I'm trying to program a split that takes in a char-array with multiple words and separates each word into their own smaller char-array. All the pointers of the smaller char-arrays are kept in a pointer array so I can return a double pointer.

Can you take a look at my code and see if you see any errors. When I try to run my program my computer gets gradually slower, after 3-4 seconds I can't move my mouse or alt+f4 my editor. So something has to be seriously wrong!

Also I'm completely new to C-programming so I will most definitely have a silly mistake in there.

```
char **split(char *s) {

char **result;
int wrd_cnt = 2; //I'm adding NULL at the end of the pointer-array.


//Counts the number of words to allocate memory for the pointer-array.
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    if(s[i] == ' ') {
        wrd_cnt++;
    }
}
result = malloc(wrd_cnt * sizeof(char*));

//Counts letters in each word to allocate memory for every single small char-array with malloc.
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < (wrd_cnt); j++) {
        int char_cnt = 0;
        for(int k = 0; s[i] != ' ' || s[i] != '\0'; k++, i++) {
            char_cnt++;
            result[j] = malloc(char_cnt * sizeof(char));
        }
    }
}

//Puts each word into their own place in the pointer array.
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < (wrd_cnt); j++) {
        for(int k = 0; s[i] != ' ' || s[i] != '\0'; k++, i++) {
            result[j][k] = s[i];
        }
    }
}

result[wrd_cnt-1] = NULL;
return result;
}
```

Comment: `s[i] != ' ' || s[i] != '\0'` should be `s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\0'`, otherwise you'll go outside the string bounds.

Comment: \t and \v should be considered

Comment: @AndreaBiondo Wouldn't that mean the condition is for the s[i] to be both ' ' and '\0' to meet condition? That is not possible?

Comment: @user3121023 Why is that? Because the conditions is wrong?

Comment: @Magnarok No, with `&&` you're saying "loop if the character is not a space *and* not a NUL", while with `||` you're saying "loop if the character is not a space *or* not a NUL". `s[i] != ' ' || s[i] != '\0'` will be *always* true, because one of `s[i] != ' '` or `s[i] != '\0'` will always be true. So you have an infinite loop.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo Of course, thank you!

Comment: And as @user3121023 says, `result[j] = malloc(...)` should be in the `j` loop, not in the `k` one.

Comment: @user3121023 So I can't allocate memory in a double loop? Do you have any solutions in mind?

Comment: @user3121023 Can I allocate them all at once or do I have to jump back and forth somehow?

Comment: @user3121023 Then I think I will have a problem with the char_cnt resetting to 0 (or 1 if adding \0) when moving malloc to the j loop. Not allowed to use sscanf, sorry for the bother.

Comment: @user3121023 Ah, of course! Thank you very much, you have helped me alot! Now my only problem is that the last word is put into the first array and the following being empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation the loops using j and k can be removed and instead increment and reset i, j and char_cnt based on the i loop as the s array is processed, similar to what you had done for wrd_cnt in the first loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **split(char *s);

int main ( void) {
    char **output = NULL;
    int each = 0;

    char line[99] = " string to   parse for words ";
    output = split ( line);

    each = 0;
    while ( output[each]) {
        printf ( "%s\n", output[each]);
        each++;
    }
    each = 0;
    while ( output[each]) {
        free ( output[each]);
        each++;
    }
    free ( output);

    exit ( 0);
}

char **split(char *s) {

    char **result;
    int wrd_cnt = 2; //I'm adding NULL at the end of the pointer-array.
    int char_cnt = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    //Counts the number of words to allocate memory for the pointer-array.
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if(s[i] == ' ') {
            wrd_cnt++;
        }
    }
    if ( ( result = malloc(wrd_cnt * sizeof(char*))) == NULL) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "malloc failure\n");
        exit ( 1);
    }
    //Counts letters in each word to allocate memory for every single small char-array with malloc.
    char_cnt = 1;
    j = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if ( s[i] == ' ') {
            if ( ( result[j] = malloc(char_cnt * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "malloc failure\n");
                exit ( 1);
            }
            j++;
            char_cnt = 1;
            continue;
        }
        char_cnt++;
    }
    if ( j == wrd_cnt - 2) {
        //allocate for last word
        if ( ( result[j] = malloc(char_cnt * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "malloc failure\n");
            exit ( 1);
        }
        j++;
        result[j] = NULL;
    }
    result[wrd_cnt - 1] = NULL;//just to make sure the last pointer is null

    //Puts each word into their own place in the pointer array.
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if ( s[i] == ' ') {
            result[j][k] = '\0';//for space only so [j][0] is '\0'
            k = 0;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        result[j][k] = s[i];
        k++;
        result[j][k] = '\0';//for last word if there is no final space in s[]
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the comments above your code scares me because of all the malloc() calls you do, one for each word. This means you must also free each word. This leaves programs open to memory leaks.

Given that this is C, which allows lots of casting, you can use a single malloc to hold both the (char *) pointer array AND the actual words.

```
 char **split(char const *s) {

     char   **result;   // 
     char    *target;   // where in result chars stored
     size_t   s_strlen = strlen(s);  // length of s
     int      wrd_cnt = 2;    //I'm adding NULL at the end of the pointer-array.
   {
     char const *sx;
     for ( sx = s; sx = strpbrk( sx, " \t\n\r" ); sx++ )
     {
         wrd_cnt++;
     }
   }

     result = malloc( (wrd_cnt * sizeof(char *)) + s_strlen + 2 );
                                         /* allow for \0 and possible ' ' */

     target = (char *)(result + wrd_cnt);  /* where to save words */
     strcpy( target, s );       /* copy to target known to be big enough */
     if ( s_strlen > 0 && target[s_strlen-1] != ' ' )
         strcat( target + s_strlen, " " );  /* assure ends in space */

   {
     char   *tx, *tnext;
     int     n;
     n = 0;
     for ( tx = target; tnext = strpbrk( tx, " \t\n\r" ); tx = tnext + 1 )
     {
         result[n++] = tx;      /* remember pointer */
         *tnext = '\0';         /* terminate word */
     }
     result[n] = NULL;          /* null termination */
   }

     return result;
 }
```